# addEventListener

Tags: javascript, eventos

Estoy intentando hacer que un boton haga una funcion.No me funciona el addEventListener. Escribo la funcion de varias formas pero nada. Hay algo mal?

```
<!--html--> 
<input type="button"  value="Agregar" class="botoni"></button>

//js
let boton=document.querySelector(".botoni").addEventListener("onclick",()=>{
    alert("ok")
})
```

en cambio si me funciona con asi, por lo que descarto que el html no este leyendo el js

```
let boton=document.querySelector(".botoni").setAttribute("onclick", "imprimir()")
```

Comment: el script para conectar el archivo js lo pongo al final de todo antes q termine el body

Comment: En el addEventListener no es `onclick`, es `click`, aunque no tiene mucho sentido que le hagas un `let` a eso.

Comment: con click tampoco funciona

Comment: Pues mira aqui:  https://jsfiddle.net/gp9kt8Le/   a mi me funciona

Comment: debo tener algo mal en el html

Comment: Ponlo entero en la pregunta pues, asi podremos ayudarte mejor, pero ya has visto que funcionar funciona... si lo tienes todo en un solo archivo asegurate de poner el javascript entre `<script></script>`

Comment: ahi comenzo a funcionar, y la verdad no se que cambie...lo que si en el codigo html no se me añadio el click. Funciona, pero quedo asi mismo, cuando chequeo en elements. 

<input type="button"  value="Agregar" class="botoni"></button>

Answer (score 0):

Tu código tiene un par de detalles:

- La variable `boton` no es necesaria. Pero si la vas a usar debes separar el ´addEventListener´ en otra línea, o si no `boton` quedará como *undefined*.
- El evento que quieres oir es *click*. Tu segundo intento funcionó porque hay un atributo llamado *onClick* que permite asignar una función al evento *click*.

Este ejemplo lo puedes probar aquí directamente (haciendo clic en el botón azul "Ejecutar"):

```js
//js
let boton = document.querySelector(".botoni")
boton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  alert("ok")
})
```

```html
<!--html-->
<input type="button" value="Agregar" class="botoni">
```

NOTA: Se supone que el HTML se debe cargar antes de ejecutar el JS, en el ejemplo se ven invertidos, pero es por el plugin de ejecución.

## UPDATE:

Si son varios botones, puedes usar `querySelectorAll`, pero necesitarás algo para identificar en cual botón el usuario hizo clic:

```js
//js
let botones = document.querySelectorAll(".botoni")
botones.forEach((item) => {
  item.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    const nombre = e.target.dataset['nombre']
    alert("ok: " + nombre)
  })
})
```

```html
<!--html-->
<input type="button" value="Agregar" data-nombre="Juan" class="botoni">
<input type="button" value="Agregar" data-nombre="Maria" class="botoni">
<input type="button" value="Agregar" data-nombre="Carlos" class="botoni">
```

Otra opción, si tus botones hacen diferentes tareas (agregar, eliminar, modificar...), sería que cada una tenga un `id` y un `eventListener` separado.

Comment: Veo que has dejado el `</button>` en el html. Ya puestos a crear una respuesta por un fallo tipográfico lo arreglamos todo :-)

Comment: Gracias, corregido!, eso me pasa por copiar y pegar (-_-')

Comment: Gracias! lo que noto que al llamarlo por clase, si tengo varios botones con esa clase, solo funciona el click en el primer elemento. Quizas deberia ponerle id y poner el click a cada id

Comment: @Nam deberias ser mas concreto en tu pregunta la próxima vez, explicando con más detalle y sin miedo a colgar más codigo, pues el problema que dices ahora no se corresponde con tu pregunta, sino que es relativo al uso de `querySelector`, que solo devuelve el primer elemento que encuentra **siempre**... Si necesitas acceder a todos debes usar `querySelectorAll` pero de forma distinta, pues debes recorrerlo con un bucle despues.

Comment: es que las preguntar van surgiendo a medida que estudio...jaja gracias igual

Comment: @Nam en este caso, si hubieras dicho desde el principio que esa clase se usaba en más de un elemento, seguramente, aparte del onclick, ya hubieramos resuelto lo del querySelector tambien, pues tenia relación con tu problema que "ahora me va" "ahora no me va", pues estabas clickeando distintos elementos con la misma clase.  Yo lo siento pero me salgo de esta pregunta. Si quieres la reformulas de nuevo de forma completa y quizás vuelvo a entrar, y sino pues te deseo suerte y a ver si alguien quiere seguir ayudandote. Saludos

Comment: igual ya esta respondida la pregunta